# Clickable image messing up menu

Tags: html, image

This image:

[image]

Alright well I'm using this code for it to make the logo on the left a clickable image

```
a href="http://nucammer.com"><img src="logo.jpg" alt="Nucammer.com" align="left"
```

But if I take out the link so just `img src="logo.jpg" alt="Nucammer.com" align="left"`

it turns it back to the way it should look here

[image]

I don't see how making an image clickable screws up the menubar

Comment: Probably you have Css styles changing de a tags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
a.image {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Where .image is the class you'll give to your anchor tag.